# Java swing sleep command

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating a board game with AI and I'm trying to have the square the AI chose to place his game piece in to flash for a second or two and only then to conduct the chosen move. My attempts are as follow:

**Thread.Sleep**

```
button.setBackground(Color.pink);
Thread.sleep(800);
button.setBackground((new JButton()).getBackground());
Thread.sleep(800);
button.setBackground(Color.pink);
Thread.sleep(800);
button.setBackground((new JButton()).getBackground());
Thread.sleep(800);
```

**Thread**

```
Thread flash = new Thread(new ButtonFlashThread(button));
flash.start();
```

**Callable**

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<Boolean> task = es.submit(new ButtonFlashThread(button));
```

both with the class (for the thread one it was implementing Runnable and instead of public Boolean call() it was public void run())

```
public class ButtonFlashThread implements Callable<Boolean> {

private int sleepTime = 800;
private JButton button;

public ButtonFlashThread(JButton b) {
    button = b;
}

public Boolean call() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        button.setBackground(Color.pink);   
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        button.setBackground((new JButton()).getBackground());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**InvokeLater**

```
Runnable flashON = new Runnable() {
         public void run() { button.setBackground(Color.pink); } };
     Runnable flashOFF = new Runnable() {
         public void run() { button.setBackground((new JButton()).getBackground()); } };
         javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(flashON);
         javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(flashOFF);
         javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(flashON);
         javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(flashOFF);
```

**Timer**

```
    ActionListener flashON = new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){ button.setBackground(Color.pink); } };
    ActionListener flashOFF = new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { button.setBackground((new JButton()).getBackground()); } };

    int sleep = 800;
    Timer timer = new Timer(sleep, flashON); timer.setRepeats(false); timer.start();
    timer = new Timer(sleep, flashOFF); timer.setRepeats(false); timer.start();
    timer = new Timer(sleep, flashON); timer.setRepeats(false); timer.start();
    timer = new Timer(sleep, flashOFF); timer.setRepeats(false); timer.start();
```

The Thread.Sleep command froze the GUI and the all other attempts continued with the code while the button was flashing. Not as I need it to be. I want the button the flash and the code to pause, until the button is done flashing and only then resume. Basically I'm looking for a way to do the following:

```
//Find desired move (done)
//Flash the JButton a few times to indicate selected move
//Do following move (done)
```

In that order exactly.

***EDIT 1:***
the following implementation

```
private void flashButton(JButton button) {      
    class MoveTimerListener implements ActionListener {
        private boolean flashOn = false;
        private int count;
        private int MAX_COUNT = 5;
        private JButton button;

        public MoveTimerListener(JButton b) {
            button = b;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            flashOn = !flashOn;
            if (count >= MAX_COUNT) { // MAX_COUNT is an int constant
                // reached max -- stop timer
                ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                flashOn = false;

                aiMove();
                updateGUI();
            }

            if (flashOn)
                button.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            else
                button.setBackground((new JButton()).getBackground());
            count++;
        }
    }

    Timer t = new Timer(5000, new MoveTimerListener(button));
    t.start();
    updateGUI();
}
```

didn't pause the code and let it continue while the button was still flashing in the background, long after the code had finished.

***EDIT 2:***
I implemented your example like this:

```
private void flashButton() {        
    _moveTimer = new Timer(100, new MoveTimerListener());
    _moveTimer.start();
    updateGUI();
}

private class MoveTimerListener implements ActionListener {
    private boolean flashOn = false;
    private int count;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        flashOn = !flashOn;
        if (count >= 20) {
            ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
            flashOn = false;
            _gm.makeMove(aiMove[0], aiMove[1]);
        }

        if (flashOn) {
            _boardButtons[aiMove[0]][aiMove[1]].setBackground(Color.yellow);
        } else {
            _boardButtons[aiMove[0]][aiMove[1]].setBackground((new JButton()).getBackground());
        }
        count++;
    }
}
```

yet it seem the code always skips the actionPerformed method. Have I done something wrong?

***EDIT 3:*** Not so small but runnable program. The problematic code is in lines 95-140

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GameGUI extends JFrame implements MouseListener {

private GameManager _gm;

private JLabel[] _scores;
private JLabel[] _players;
private JPanel _contentPane;
private JButton[] _toolbarButtons;
private JButton[][] _boardButtons;
private Timer _moveTimer;
private int[] aiMove;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                GameManager gm = new GameManager();
                //gm.addPlayer(new Player("player", 2, 0));
                gm.addPlayer(new Player("random", 2, 1));
                gm.addPlayer(new Player("max kills ai", 1, 2));
                gm.initBoard(8, 8);
                GameGUI frame = new GameGUI(gm);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public GameGUI(GameManager gm) {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    _contentPane = new JPanel();
    _boardButtons = new JButton[gm.getBoardSize()[0]][gm.getBoardSize()[1]];
    _gm = gm;
    addWindowGUI(_contentPane);
    setContentPane(_contentPane);
    aiMove();
    updateGUI();
}

private void addWindowGUI(JPanel cp) {
    cp.setLayout(new BoxLayout(_contentPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    JPanel gameInfo = new JPanel();
    gameInfo.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    //Game grid
    JPanel gameGrid = new JPanel();
    int buttonSize = 40;
    gameGrid.setLayout(new GridLayout(_gm.getBoardSize()[0], _gm.getBoardSize()[1]));
    for (int i = 0; i < _boardButtons.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < _boardButtons[i].length; j++) {
            _boardButtons[i][j] = new JButton();
            _boardButtons[i][j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(buttonSize, buttonSize));
            _boardButtons[i][j].addMouseListener(this);
            gameGrid.add(_boardButtons[i][j]);
        }
    gameInfo.add(gameGrid);
    cp.add(gameInfo);
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if (!_gm.getCurrentPlayer().isAI()) {
        //Find desired move and conduct it
        for (int i = 0; i < _boardButtons.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < _boardButtons[i].length; j++)
                if (e.getSource().equals(_boardButtons[i][j]))
                    _gm.makeMove(i,j);

        aiMove();
        updateGUI();
    }
}

public void aiMove() {
    int winner = _gm.isGameOver();
    while (winner == -1 && _gm.getCurrentPlayer().getAI() != 0) {
        updateGUI();
        aiMove = _gm.getNextAIMove();
        flashButton();
        winner = _gm.isGameOver();
    }

    if (winner != -1) {
        // Winner
    }
}

private void flashButton() {        
    _moveTimer = new Timer(100, new MoveTimerListener());
    _moveTimer.start();
    updateGUI();
}

private class MoveTimerListener implements ActionListener {
    private boolean flashOn = false;
    private int count;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        flashOn = !flashOn;
        if (count >= 20) {
            ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
            flashOn = false;
            _gm.makeMove(aiMove[0], aiMove[1]);
        }

        if (flashOn) {
            _boardButtons[aiMove[0]][aiMove[1]].setBackground(Color.yellow);
        } else {
            _boardButtons[aiMove[0]][aiMove[1]].setBackground((new JButton()).getBackground());
        }
        count++;
    }
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    if (!_gm.getCurrentPlayer().isAI()) {
        LinkedList<int[]> l = new LinkedList<int[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < _boardButtons.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < _boardButtons[i].length; j++)
                if (e.getSource().equals(_boardButtons[i][j]))
                    l = _gm.canPlace(i,j);
        for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
            int[] temp = l.get(i);
            _boardButtons[temp[0]][temp[1]].setBackground(Color.yellow);
        }
    }
}
private void updateGUI() {
    for (int i = 0; i < _boardButtons.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < _boardButtons[i].length; j++)
            if (_gm.getBoard().stoneAt(i, j) == 1)
                _boardButtons[i][j].setBackground(Color.green);
            else if (_gm.getBoard().stoneAt(i, j) == 2)
                _boardButtons[i][j].setBackground(Color.red);
}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) { updateGUI(); }

//Not relevant
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) { }
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) { }


//Other classes
public static class GameManager {
    private int _turn;
    private Player[] _players;
    private GameBoard _board;
    private GameLog _log;

    public int getTurn() { return _turn; }
    public Player[] getPlayers() { return _players; }
    public GameBoard getBoard() { return _board; }

    public GameManager() {
        _turn = 0;
        _players = new Player[0];
    }

    public int[] getNextAIMove() {
        AI ai = new AI();
        return ai.play(_players[_turn].getAI(), _board, _players[_turn].getColour());
    }

    public void initBoard(int m, int n) {
        int[] colours = new int[_players.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < colours.length; i++)
            colours[i] = _players[i].getColour();
        _board = new GameBoard(m, n, colours);
        updateScore();
    }

    public void addPlayer(Player p) {
        Player[] temp = _players;
        _players = new Player[temp.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
            _players[i] = temp[i];
        _players[temp.length] = new Player(p);

        Random rnd = new Random();
        _turn = rnd.nextInt(_players.length);
    }

    private void advanceTurn() {
        _turn++;
        if(_turn == _players.length) 
            _turn = 0;
    }

    public void makeMove(int y, int x) {
        if (_board.place(y, x, _players[_turn].getColour()) != 0) {
            updateScore();
            advanceTurn();
        }
    }

    public LinkedList<int[]> canPlace(int y, int x) {
        return _board.canPlace(y, x, _players[_turn].getColour());
    }

    public int[] getBoardSize() {
        return _board.getSize();
    }

    private void updateScore() {
        int[] scores = new int[_players.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < _board.getSize()[0]; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < _board.getSize()[1]; j++)
                for (int j2 = 0; j2 < _players.length; j2++)
                    if (_players[j2].getColour() == _board.stoneAt(i, j))
                        scores[j2]++;
        for (int i = 0; i < _players.length; i++) {
            _players[i].setScore(scores[i]);
        }
    }

    public int isGameOver() {
        int winner = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < _players.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < _board.getSize()[0]; j++)
                for (int j2 = 0; j2 < _board.getSize()[1]; j2++)
                    if (canPlace(j, j2).size() != 0)
                        return -1;
            advanceTurn();
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < _players.length; i++)
            if (_players[i].getPoints() > _players[winner].getPoints())
                winner = i;
        return winner;
    }
    public Player getCurrentPlayer() {
        return _players[_turn];
    }
}

public static class AI {
    public int[] play(int diff, GameBoard board, int colour) {
        //List all possible moves
        int[] move = new int[2];
        LinkedList<int[]> posibilities = new LinkedList<int[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < board.getSize()[0]; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < board.getSize()[1]; j++)
                if (board.canPlace(i, j, colour).size() > 0) {
                    int[] temp = {i, j};
                    posibilities.add(temp);
                }

        //Choose a move according to AI difficulty
        switch (diff) {
        case 1: // Easy - random
            Random r = new Random();
            move = posibilities.get(r.nextInt(posibilities.size()));
            break;

        case 2: // Medium - max kills
            int max = 0, kills = board.canPlace(posibilities.get(0)[0], posibilities.get(0)[1], colour).size();
            for (int i = 1; i < posibilities.size(); i++) {
                int[] temp = posibilities.get(i);
                int tempkills = board.canPlace(temp[0], temp[1], colour).size();
                if (kills < tempkills) {
                    kills = tempkills;
                    max = i;
                }
            }
            move = posibilities.get(max);
            break;

        case 3: // Hard
            break;
        }

        return move;
    }
}

public static class GameBoard {
    private int[][] _board;
    private int _m;
    private int _n;

    public GameBoard(int m, int n, int[] colours) {
        _m = m;
        _n = n;
        _board = new int[m][n];
        for (int i = 0; i < _board.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < _board[i].length; j++)
                _board[i][j] = 0;
        if (_m % 2 == 0 && _n % 2 == 0) {
            _board[m/2][n/2] = _board[m/2 - 1][n/2 - 1] = colours[0];
            _board[m/2][n/2 - 1] = _board[m/2 - 1][n/2] = colours[1];
        }

        int[][] testBoard = {
                {2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2},
                {2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2},
                {1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1},
                {2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1},
                {2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2},
                {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
                {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
                {1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0}};
        //_board = testBoard;
    }

    public int[] getSize() {
        int[] size = {_m, _n};
        return size;
    }

    public LinkedList<int[]> canPlace(int y, int x, int colour) {
        LinkedList<int[]> eats = new LinkedList<int[]>();
        if (_board[y][x] != 0) return eats;
        int i;
        if (existsAnotherIn("u", y, x, colour)) {
            i = 1;
            while (isInBounds(y + i, x) && _board[y + i][x] != colour && _board[y + i][x] != 0) {
                int[] temp = {y + i, x};
                eats.add(temp);
                i++;
            }
        }
        if (existsAnotherIn("d", y, x, colour)) {
            i = 1;
            while (isInBounds(y - i, x) && _board[y - i][x] != colour && _board[y - i][x] != 0) {
                int[] temp = {y - i, x};
                eats.add(temp);
                i++;
            }       
        }
        if (existsAnotherIn("l", y, x, colour)) {
            i = 1;
            while (isInBounds(y, x - i) && _board[y][x - i] != colour && _board[y][x - i] != 0) {
                int[] temp = {y, x - i};
                eats.add(temp);
                i++;
            }
        }
        if (existsAnotherIn("r", y, x, colour)) {
            i = 1;
            while (isInBounds(y, x + i) && _board[y][x + i] != colour && _board[y][x + i] != 0) {
                int[] temp = {y, x + i};
                eats.add(temp);
                i++;
            }
        }
        if (existsAnotherIn("ul", y, x, colour)) {
            i = 1;
            while (isInBounds(y + i, x - i) && _board[y + i][x - i] != colour && _board[y + i][x - i] != 0) {
                int[] temp = {y + i, x - i};
                eats.add(temp);
                i++;
            }
        }
        if (existsAnotherIn("ur", y, x, colour)) {
            i = 1;
            while (isInBounds(y + i, x + i) && _board[y + i][x + i] != colour && _board[y + i][x + i] != 0) {
                int[] temp = {y + i, x + i};
                eats.add(temp);
                i++;
            }
        }
        if (existsAnotherIn("dl", y, x, colour)) {
            i = 1;
            while (isInBounds(y - i, x - i) && _board[y - i][x - i] != colour && _board[y - i][x - i] != 0) {
                int[] temp = {y - i, x - i};
                eats.add(temp);
                i++;
            }
        }
        if (existsAnotherIn("dr", y, x, colour)) {
            i = 1;
            while (isInBounds(y - i, x + i) && _board[y - i][x + i] != colour && _board[y - i][x + i] != 0) {
                int[] temp = {y - i, x + i};
                eats.add(temp);
                i++;
            }
        }
        return eats;
    }

    private boolean isInBounds(int i, int j) {
        return i >= 0 && j >= 0 && i < _m && j < _n;
    }

    private boolean existsAnotherIn(String lane, int vo, int ho, int colour) {
        int v = 0, h = 0;

        do {
            if ((v != 0 || h != 0) && _board[vo + v][ho + h] == colour) return true;

            if (lane.contains("u"))         v++;
            else if (lane.contains("d"))    v--;
            if (lane.contains("r"))         h++;
            else if (lane.contains("l"))    h--;
        } while (isInBounds(vo + v, ho + h) && _board[vo + v][ho + h] != 0);
        return false;
    }

    public int place(int y, int x, int colour) {
        LinkedList<int[]> stonesToEat = canPlace(y, x, colour);
        if (!stonesToEat.isEmpty()) {
            _board[y][x] = colour;
            for (int i = 0; i < stonesToEat.size(); i++) {
                int[] place = stonesToEat.get(i);
                _board[place[0]][place[1]] = colour;
            }
        }
        return stonesToEat.size();
    }

    public String toString() {
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < _board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < _board[0].length; j++) {
                s+=_board[i][j]+"\t";
            }
            s += "\n";
        }
        return s;
    }

    public int stoneAt(int i, int j) {
        return _board[i][j];
    }
}

public static class Player {
    private String _name;
    private int _points;
    private int _colour;
    private int _ai;

    public Player(String name, int colour, int ai) {
        _name = name;
        _points = 0;
        _colour = colour;
        _ai = ai;
    }

    public void setScore(int s) {
        _points = s;
    }

    public Player(Player p) {
        _name = p._name;
        _points = p._points;
        _colour = p._colour;
        _ai = p._ai;
    }

    public boolean isAI() {
        return _ai != 0;
    }

    public void addPoints(int add) { _points += add; }

    public int getColour() { return _colour; }

    public String getName() { return _name; }

    public int getPoints() { return _points; }

    public int getAI() { return _ai; }
}

public class GameLog extends GameManager {
    private int _startingPlayer;
    private LinkedList<String> _moves;

    public GameLog(int startPlayer) {
        _startingPlayer = startPlayer;
        _moves = new LinkedList<String>();
    }

    public void addMove(String m) {
        _moves.add(m);
    }

    public int getStartingPlayer() { return _startingPlayer; }

    public LinkedList<String> getMoves() { return _moves; }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You're over thinking this. Just create **one single Swing Timer**, that's it, and give it a state -- i.e., give its ActionListener fields that change, one, a boolean that represents when to flash that you turn true and false, another, an int that counts number of flashes and that turns the Timer off after a certain number is reached, and that then makes the move.

Something as simple as

```
class MoveTimerListener implements ActionListener {
  private boolean flashOn = false;
  private int count;

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     flashOn = !flashOn;
     if (count >= MAX_COUNT) { // MAX_COUNT is an int constant
        // reached max -- stop timer
        ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
        flashOn = false;

        // TODO: place code to make move here
     }

     if (flashOn) {
        // TODO: place code to flash here
     }
     count++;
  }
}
```

The total running time for this would be MAX_COUNT * the timer's delay.

For example,

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FlashingTimerGui extends JPanel {
   private static final int MAX_COUNT = 20;
   private static final int IMG_WIDTH = 60;
   private static final int SIDES = 3;
   public static final int MOVE_TIMER_DELAY = 100;
   private Icon blankIcon;
   private Icon blackIcon;
   private Icon redIcon;
   private List<JLabel> labelList = new ArrayList<>();
   private Timer moveTimer;
   private int labelListIndex = 0;

   public FlashingTimerGui() {
      blankIcon = createIcon(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
      blackIcon = createIcon(Color.black);
      redIcon = createIcon(Color.red);

      JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(SIDES, SIDES));
      gridPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
      for (int i = 0; i < SIDES * SIDES; i++) {
         JLabel label = new JLabel(blankIcon);
         label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
         gridPanel.add(label);
         labelList.add(label);
      }

      JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
      buttonPanel.add(new JButton(new MoveAction("Move")));

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(gridPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

      labelList.get(labelListIndex).setIcon(blackIcon);
   }

   private Icon createIcon(Color color) {
      BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_WIDTH,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      g2.setColor(color);
      int x = 4;
      int y = x;
      int w = IMG_WIDTH - 2 * x;
      int h = w;
      g2.fillOval(x, y, w, h);
      g2.dispose();
      return new ImageIcon(img);
   }

   private class MoveTimerListener implements ActionListener {
      private boolean flashOn = false;
      private int count;

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         flashOn = !flashOn;
         if (count >= MAX_COUNT) { // MAX_COUNT is an int constant
            // reached max -- stop timer
            ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
            flashOn = false;

            // code to make move here
            labelList.get(labelListIndex).setIcon(blankIcon);

            labelListIndex++;
            labelListIndex %= labelList.size();
            labelList.get(labelListIndex).setIcon(blackIcon);
         }

         if (flashOn) {
            labelList.get(labelListIndex).setIcon(redIcon);
         } else {
            labelList.get(labelListIndex).setIcon(blackIcon);
         }
         count++;
      }
   }

   private class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {

      public MoveAction(String name) {
         super(name);
         int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if (moveTimer != null && moveTimer.isRunning()) {
            // timer is running -- ignore request to re-run
            return;
         }

         moveTimer = new Timer(MOVE_TIMER_DELAY, new MoveTimerListener());
         moveTimer.start();
      }

   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      FlashingTimerGui mainPanel = new FlashingTimerGui();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Flashing Timer");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }

}
```

Comment: The code still doesn't pause. After I make a move the AI does one immediately after and the flashing only then takes affect, after the move has already been done.

Comment: @iMax531: Run my code to see what I mean. If you're still stuck, then you're going to have to create and post something like what I posted above: a *very* simple and small self-contained program that demonstrates your problem for us, an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The code skips actionPerformed method for some reason. Code in edit 2

Comment: @iMax531: if you can, place that code in a small runnable program (edit 3) so that we can test it for ourselves (like I've done above) and hopefully modify it to get it to work.

Comment: Not very small but it's runnable. The code discussed is in lines 95-140 (EDIT 3)

Comment: @iMax531: OK, it runs, but it's not displaying anything for me. And I've found that the reason is this never ending while loop, `while (winner == -1 && _gm.getCurrentPlayer().getAI() != 0) {` within your `aiMove()` method. This is not safe code for an event driven GUI program, and I will posit **shouldn't** be in an event-driven program as it will stomp all over the Swing event thread. Anyway, please let me know if you fix this, but for now, I'm going to bed. Good night and best of luck!

Comment: The condition is correct. It is always true because the method actionPerformed in MoveTimerListener doesn't get executed which is the problem